# Taking an integer (positive or negative) and splitting it into multiple rows in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

If we have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'String_Column': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'String_Column_2': ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
                   'Integer_Column': [1, -2, 3]})
```

How do I convert the table from looking like this:

| String_Column | String_Column_2 | Integer_Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 1 |
| B | Y | -2 |
| C | Z | 3 |

To looking like this:

| String_Column | String_Column_2 | Integer_Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 1 |
| B | Y | -1 |
| B | Y | -1 |
| C | Z | 1 |
| C | Z | 1 |
| C | Z | 1 |

I'm new to Python.......

Comment: Even if this can be inferred from the data, can you please [edit] the question to explicitly describe the expected logic?

Answer (score 1):

Please repeat rows absolute of the integer times and then update the integer value according to <0 or not.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'String_Column': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'String_Column_2': ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
                   'Integer_Column': [1, -2, 3]})

df_repeated = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Integer_Column'].apply(lambda x: abs(x)))].copy() # repeat rows absolute of integer
df_repeated['Integer_Column'] = df_repeated['Integer_Column'].apply(lambda x: -1 if x < 0 else 1) # if x <0: -1, else 1
df_repeated.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

print(df_repeated)
```

Output:

```
  String_Column String_Column_2  Integer_Column
0             A               X               1
1             B               Y              -1
2             B               Y              -1
3             C               Z               1
4             C               Z               1
5             C               Z               1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, which first creates a list of `1` or `-1` from each value of column `Integer_Column` and then uses [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
(df.assign(Integer_Column = df['Integer_Column']
           .map(lambda x: [np.sign(x)]*abs(x)))
 .explode('Integer_Column'))
```

---

The following solution seems to be a little bit more efficient, but not much, because of [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), as @mozway pertinently argues in a comment below.

```
signs = np.sign(df['Integer_Column'])
lengths = abs(df['Integer_Column'])

(df.assign(Integer_Column = [np.full(abs_len, sign) 
                             for sign, abs_len in zip(signs, lengths)])
 .explode('Integer_Column'))
```

---

Output:

```
  String_Column String_Column_2 Integer_Column
0             A               X              1
1             B               Y             -1
1             B               Y             -1
2             C               Z              1
2             C               Z              1
2             C               Z              1
```

Comment: That's however much less efficient than `repeat` (using lists/explode is costly) ;)

Comment: Thanks, @mozway, for having commented my solution! Indeed, the solution with `explode` takes longer, but maybe the OP's dataframe is small. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html)+[`abs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html) to duplicate the rows, and convert Integer_Column with [`numpy.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html):

```
out = (df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Integer_Column'].abs())]
         .assign(Integer_Column=lambda d: np.sign(d['Integer_Column']))
      )

# or reversing the operations, which might be a bit more efficient
# out = (df.assign(Integer_Column=lambda d: np.sign(d['Integer_Column']))
#          .loc[df.index.repeat(df['Integer_Column'].abs())]
#       )
```

Another option with [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to generate the `1`/`-1`:

```
out = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Integer_Column'].abs())]

out['Integer_Column'] /= out.groupby(level=0).transform('size')
```

Output:

```
  String_Column String_Column_2  Integer_Column
0             A               X               1
1             B               Y              -1
1             B               Y              -1
2             C               Z               1
2             C               Z               1
2             C               Z               1
```